# Can't get unique values

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using my sql to get unique values from database

My query looks as follows, but somehow I'm not able to get unique results

```
                    SELECT
            DISTINCT(company_name),
            sp_id               
        FROM
            Student_Training
        ORDER BY
            company_name
```

sp_id is the primary key, and then company_name is the companies name that needs to be unique

looks as follows

```
sp_id, company_name
1      comp1
2      comp2
3      comp2
4      comp3
```

Just not sorting this unique

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DISTINCT` will make unique rows, meaning the unique combination of the field values in your query.

The following query will return a list of all the unique company_name together with the first match for sp_id.

```
SELECT sp_id, company_name
FROM Student_Training
GROUP BY company_name
```

And as Arthur Reutenauer has suggested, it is indeed pretty deceiving that MySQL allows the `DISTINCT(fieldname)` syntax when it actually means `DISTINCT(field1, field2, ..., fieldn)`

Comment: Actually I just realized why it's so.  Editing my answer to add the explanation.

Answer (score 7):

DISTINCT works globally, on *all* the columns you SELECT.  Here you're getting distinct *pairs* of (sp_id, company_name) values, but the individual values of each column may show duplicates.

That being said, it's extremely deceiving that MySQL authorizes the syntax `SELECT DISTINCT(company_name), sp_id` when it really means `SELECT DISTINCT(company_name, sp_id)`.  You don't need the parentheses at all, by the way.

**Edit**

Actually there's a reason why `DISTINCT(company_name), sp_id` is valid syntax: adding parentheses around an expression is always legal although it can be overkill: `company_name` is the same as `(company_name)` or even `(((company_name)))`.  Hence what that piece of SQL means is really: “DISTINCT [company_name in parentheses], [sp_id]”.  The parentheses are attached to the column name, not the DISTINCT keyword, which, unlike aggregate function names, for example, does not need parentheses (`AVG sp_id` is not legal even if unambiguous for a human reader, it's *always* `AVG(sp_id)`.)

For that matter, you could write `SELECT DISTINCT company_name, (sp_id)` or `SELECT DISTINCT (company_name), (sp_id)`, it's exactly the same as the plain syntax without parentheses.  Putting the list of columns inside parentheses – `(company_name, sp_id)` – is not legal SQL syntax, though, you can only SELECT “plain” lists of columns, unparenthesized (the form's spell-checker tells me this last expression is not an English word but I don't care.  It's Friday afternoon after all).

Therefore, any database engine should accept this confusing syntax :-(

Answer (score 3):

Which `id` you want in case when a single `company_name` has two or more `id`'s?

This:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT company_name                 
FROM    Student_Training
```

will select only the `company_name`.

This:

```
SELECT  company_name, MIN(id)
FROM    Student_Training
GROUP BY
        company_name
```

will select minimal `id` for each company name.

Answer (score 2):

DISTINCT does not work the way you think it does.  It gives you a distinct record.  Stop and think about how it could return what you expect it to return. If you had a table as follows

```
id    name
1     joe
2     joe
3     james
```

If it only returned distinct names, which id would it return for joe?

You may want

```
SELECT company_name, Min(sp_id) FROM Student_Tracking GROUP BY company_name
```

or perhaps (as above) just

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_name from student_training
```